# Gedit opening an "Unsaved document" on opening files with mouse

Tags: open-files, gedit

When I open files by double-clicking a file with mouse I always get one additional "Unsaved Document X".. which is very annoying, because I have to close tham all, and click "Close without save" every time... This happens in dolphin, nautilus and krusader (those are the ones where I tried it, so I gues it's not because of a file manager).

When I try opening a file from terminal using "gedit filename" the problem is not there. It also does not happen if I open files from within gedit.

Any hints on how to fix this?

This started happening I think somewhere around the time when gnome3 came into Arch official repos.
(I use up-to-date Arch and KDE4.6)

Comment: Are you using KDE or Gnome? KDE usually defaults to single clicks while Gnome uses double clicks.

Comment: I wrote in my post that I use KDE4.6 =) and thanks, but nope - it's not about single/double clicks.. I turned single-click off a long time ago.

Comment: @wojox: OP already stated he's using KDE 4.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Felrood from Arch Linux forums [provided](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1031898#p1031898) a solution and I would like to share it here and close this question.

Gedit seems to display data from stdin in a new "Unsaved document". For example:

```
echo "foobar" | gedit
```

What can be done is this:

> right click the Kmenu button -> edit applications -> find gedit there
>   (for me that is "utilities") -> put "gedit $1 < /dev/null" in gedits
>   command field -> save

For me that solved the problem no matter whether I use krusader, dolphin, alt+f2 or something else..

Comment: That has been bugging me for a while, thanks / upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but its worth a try.

Suppose you want to open `file123`

Use the terminal to `cd` into the folder that contains this file.

Then do `ls -a`

If there exists a file named `.file123`, remove it i.e `sudo rm .file123`

Now try opening file123, the problem should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get purge gedit`
the search in Synaptic (`sudo apt-get install Synaptic` if you don't have it) for you gedit package  then go to menu *Package -> Force version* and choose the version you think is stable.

Comment: Did you read my question to the end? I wrote I use Arch Linux so - no apt-get/synaptics for me.. ;)

Comment: Maybe you can try `dpkg -P` to purge and `dpkg --force-downgrade gedit` to try go back to the older version or go to Arch Linux repository, download the archive gedit you think is stable [gedit in ArchLinux](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=gedit&maintainer=&last_update=&flagged=&limit=50) and install it using `dpkg -i --force-all Name_of_downloaded_file`

Comment: I wish I could use that yeah, but Arch does not use .deb packages at all nor is dpkg in Arch repos.. Thanks for trying though. :)